# trouble with importrange, working on a sheet, not on an other

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have been using this importrange formula :

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D0WFRUjpLPz3WrCRF_-_grvDwoGLT1EoSQJlwObbghY/edit#gid=1708147837","'0_LISTE PROJETS'!B5:B")
```

on this sheet it works :

[image]

but on this one it don't... :

[image]

the error message is this one :

Erreur // Error

Erreur d'analyse de formule. // Error of formula analysis

Comment: could be sheet locale issue; can you try replacing the comma `,` with semicolon `;` inside the formula and see what happens?!

Comment: it looks so easy for you ! thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the solution was provided by @rockinfreakshow in the comments section.

The problem was related to the region of the Google Sheet, which affects whether the `ImportRange` formula accepts a `,` or a `;` symbol to operate correctly.

You can see the change when you access to the Google documentation for`IMPORTRANGE`, and change the language to `FR` like [this](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093340?hl=fr).